# Print report on print button in odoo10

Tags: reporting, odoo-10, qweb

Hi I am having a problem in printing the report. I have coded the report format in html and then made its module and attached it with the relevant model. and upload it on my online server

First I was receiving this error : Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). Message: The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

I have solved this problem using this following link https://gist.github.com/tejastank/45b6eba13fb38e24110218e3ce50129b

Its still not printing but keeps on creating child of the report in rec_name area, please see the attachment
[image]
and showing this error on the side

[image]

Questions:

1).How I can print the report directly from the print button without getting these errors.

One of our client give us access of there ERP for some changes, I have seen there reports when we click on print button on there ERP it downloads the PDF version pf the report and then we print it. so

2). How can we download the report in PDF formate.

I am using odoo10 not odoo8. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Solution :

Downlaod this -https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

and then follow the step :
(IF  THE ABOUT WKHTMLTOPDF IS NOT INSTALL THAN AND  THAN 1ST STEP HAVE TO DO IT)
1) sudo dpkg -i http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

2) sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
3) sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin

may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. Download `wkhtmltopdf` https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/
2. Install *.deb file using this command,  `sudo dpkg -i file_name.deb`
3. If any error occur during installation execute, `sudo apt-get install -f`
4. sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
5. Restart odoo server and try.

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one might it ill help you..

```
sudo pip install Wkhtmltopdf
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all possible solutions, the only one worked so far is the installation using pip (pip3).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).